# Checking if a string belongs to an array type value to a key in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Say I have an `object` called "groups", in it there are keys whose values are arrays:

```
let groups = {
    group1: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    group2: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
};
let item = 'B';
```

How would I go about finding out that the `item` is in fact in `group1`? (**Note**: There would be a lot of groups. I'm aware I could use a `for` loop to iterate over each of the keys in the object. But would there be a faster way?)

Comment: So you want to create a function of sorts to return the keys that have values that contain the wanted item? You could get all the keys and filter them: `Object.keys(groups).filter(key => groups[key].includes(item));`.

Comment: If it's acceptable to make the values Sets instead of arrays, that will greatly speed up search time. I'd say without some kind of pre-sorting, you will at the very least need to iterate over each group.

Comment: I'll try these two, thanks.

Comment: If you insist to use this kind of data structure then yes you need to iterate every key in groups object. If you can change data structure to hashmap (aka dictionary) then you can quickly look up which group the item belong to

Comment: are the values unique?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes all the values are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for a reference to the keys of the groups.

```js
let groups = { group1: ['A', 'B', 'C'], group2: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] },
    map = new Map,
    item = 'B';

Object.keys(groups).forEach(k => groups[k].forEach(v => map.set(v, k)));

console.log(map.get(item));
```

ES5

```js
var groups = { group1: ['A', 'B', 'C'], group2: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] },
    hash = Object.create(null),
    item = 'B';

Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (k) {
    groups[k].forEach(function (v) {
        hash[v] = k;
    });
});

console.log(hash[item]);
```

Comment: Better use your 1st choice, the `for loop`, 'cause this ain't any better. There is no other way, but to loop over object properties.